# New Rep Rule Change?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

I was visiting one of my question when I saw I lost 5 rep for ***one*** down vote on my question. The question is: [Determining the First Digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075761/determining-the-first-digit/26076277#26076277)
Is there new update in the rep you lose if a question you asked is downvoted? I thought you only lost 2 rep.

Comment: "-5 8 mins ago **unupvote** Determining the First Digit" - Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 4):

You lost 5 points because someone that had previously upvoted you retracted that upvote.

[image: unupvote]

When that upvote was retracted it looked, to you, like you'd received a downvote because the total score decreased by one. Once you reach 1K rep, you can see the Upvote/Downvote split more clearly.

[image: vote split]

Comment: An "unupvote" :). SO the wordsmith.